# How can I get data to input from my select option

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

The options for the select menu are created from a database. I want to print the value of the selected option on the input. The code below only prints the first option value. I want to print them all. thanks.

```
<?php 
    $sql2 = "select * from add_meta";
    $sonuc2= $conn->query($sql2);
    if($sonuc2->num_rows>0){
        while($kayitlar2 = $sonuc2->fetch_object()){
            if($kayitlar2->isim!="Renk")
            {

?>

    <select id="selectid" name="<?php $kayitlar2->isim; ?>" class="sec" onchange="degergoster()" >
    <option id="barkodd"   value=""  style="display:none;"><?php echo $kayitlar2->isim; ?> seçin</option>
    <?php
                $sql = "select * from add_barkod where kat_list in('$kayitlar2->isim')";
                $sonuc= $conn->query($sql);
                if($sonuc->num_rows>0){
                    while($kayitlar = $sonuc->fetch_object()){ 
    ?> 
            <option name="selectname1"  value="<?php echo $kayitlar->ekle_hane;?>"><?php echo $kayitlar->ekle_isim; }} ?></option>
    </select>


<?php
        }   }}
?>
```

```
<input id="e" name="varyantkod"  class="sec">
```

Javascript code:

```
function degergoster() {
    var selectkutu = document.getElementById("selectid");
    var selectkutu_value = selectkutu.options[selectkutu.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementById("e").value=selectkutu_value;
}
```

Comment: I am new to software. Can you write the codes?eyy

Answer (score 0):

just get the value of the select object and add that to the value of the input
change

```
document.getElementById("selectid");
```

to

```
document.getElementById("selectid").value;
```

This should work